# How to clear text field using javascript with a condition?

Tags: javascript, html

I want if I clear the text field #t1, text field #d1 should clear. But last two lines dont do it....

```
function utl()
{

    var a = document.getElementById('t1');
    var z = document.getElementById('d1');
    if (a!=0)
        {
            var y = parseFloat(a.value) * 100;
            y = y || 0;
            z.value = y.toFixed(2);
        }
    else if (a==0)
        z.value = 0;
    else if (a=='')
        z='';
```

Comment: What did your investigation reveal? where inside the function do you think the problem lies?

Comment: You're not setting the value of z like in your first else if.

Answer (score 1):

`a` is a DOM element, and so it will always be `!= 0` as the `!=` operator will coerce it to a string, and then to a number, and that number will be `!= 0`.

You probably wanted to use the `.value` property:

```
var a = document.getElementById('t1').value;
```

But you'd still have a problem: The `value` of an input is always a string. In JavaScript, the `==` and `!=` operators do type coercion, and `""` is `==` `0`. So your third statement, `z=''`, will never be reached.

You can use the *strict* equality operators to figure out what's going on:

```
var a = document.getElementById('t1').value;
var z = document.getElementById('d1');
if (a === "") {   // <== Note! === rather than ==
    z.value = "";
} else {
    a = +a; // Convert to number intentionally
    if (a != 0) {
        var y = a * 100;
        y = y || 0;
        z.value = y.toFixed(2);
    } else if (a == 0) {
        z.value = "0";
    }
}
```

The *strict* equality (`===`) and inequality (`!==`) operators don't do type coercion, so although `"" == 0` is true, `"" === 0` is false.

That line where I converted to a number:

```
a = +a;
```

...is only one of the many options available. Using `+str` to convert to a number is the strictest way, but you don't have direct control over the number base. You could also use:

```
a = parseInt(a, 10); // If you're expecting an integer, or
a = parseFloat(a);   // If it may have a fractional portion
```

...assuming you want base 10 (decimal), but note that they ignore trailing characters, and so `parseInt("123laksdjflk", 10)` is `123`. In contrast, `+str` (or `Number(str)`) will say that's `Nan` because they consider the entire string, not just the first part.